# How requirejs load javascript async?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am wondering anyone knows the internal of Requirejs, why it can load js asynchronourly? I know Javascript has no thread, how can async done by  requirejs?

Answer (score 6):

## How RequireJS works?

Each module is contained inside a `define` call, which defines the module dependencies. With that, RequireJS makes a kind of tree to order each module from the one without dependencies, to the one with the most dependencies.

A module with only one dependency could be the one that depends on everything, if its dependency depends on another module, which depends on 2-3 other modules, and then it goes on like that.

```
define(['some/dep'], function(someDep){ /* module code */ });
```

In that order, RequireJS creates a `<script>` tag with the url to the module file and it inserts that script tag at the end of the `<head>`. **The browser** loads the JavaScript files and **runs them in the order that they are present in the HTML.**

Then, when every dependency is defined for the module to run, the function of that module is called with each dependency (previously defined) injected into the module factory function, and its result is stored.

## How can it be async without threads?

**It's async, but not necessarily parallel**. Loading scripts can be parallel as the browser (at least chrome for sure) makes multiple connections to the server to fetch more files at once, but this has nothing to do with JS.

**The async nature of JavaScript comes in an event-loop.**

Each async callback is put in an event queue and when the synchronous call stack has completely finished executing, the next event callback from the queue is called.

It's easier to grasp when you see it, and you can in the chrome's dev tools **Timeline** tab.

[image: Async callstacks in chrome's dev tools]